# Display multiple MapPolygons via ListView and ListModel

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to display multiple MapPolygons. To structre it nicely, I would like to define the polygons in a separated file. 
After some googling around, I think an approach with ListView and ListModel could work.

So far I tried to define the complete `MapPolygon` inside the `ListElement{}`. This produced an error, that a `ListElement{}` can not contain any nested elements. 
So I defiend a viarable `path` and `color` in the `ListElement{}` and tried to delegate those to a MapPolygon. 
This produces the error: "ListElement: cannot use script for property value"

The ListView:

```
ListView {
        model: PolygonCoords {}
        delegate: MapPolygon {
            color: color
            path:   path
        }
    }
```

The ListModel, PolygonCoords.qml:

```
ListModel{
    ListElement{
            color: "blue"
            path: [ //very big
                {latitude: 47.30985701233802, longitude:  8.957498557565305},
                {latitude: 48.31223969058969, longitude:  12.959643094792634},
                {latitude: 50.31281785500094, longitude:  12.960823612887165},
                {latitude: 47.31281654102718, longitude:  8.962966471196324},
                {latitude: 47.30862993050194, longitude:  8.963243902017013},
                {latitude: 47.30863115391583, longitude:  8.963151349827395},
                {latitude: 47.30697209667029, longitude:  8.962058898768426},
                {latitude: 47.30985701233802, longitude:  8.957498557565305}
            ]
    }

    ListElement {
            color: "red"
            path: [ //very big
                {latitude: 45.30985701233802, longitude:  7.957498557565305},
                {latitude: 41.31223969058969, longitude:  11.959643094792634},
                {latitude: 54.31281785500094, longitude:  11.960823612887165},
                {latitude: 45.31281654102718, longitude:  7.962966471196324},
                {latitude: 45.30862993050194, longitude:  7.963243902017013},
                {latitude: 45.30863115391583, longitude:  7.963151349827395},
                {latitude: 45.30697209667029, longitude:  7.962058898768426},
                {latitude: 45.30985701233802, longitude:  7.957498557565305}
            ]
    }
}
```

How do I have to change my `path`-Variable that it is not read as a script and 
is the ListView even the right approach or is there a better option?

@Update Thanks to @folibis, I got it working with a Repeater as long the path and the repeater are in the same file as the map. Since the file with the map is already huge, I would like to move as much as possible in its own file.

I cannot begin a file with `property var points`, so I thought of using `Item` as a wrapper in PolygonCoords.qml:

```
Item {

 property var points: [
        {
                color: Qt.rgba(0, 80, 128, 0.5),
                path: [ //very big
                    {latitude: 47.30985701233802, longitude:  8.957498557565305},
                    {latitude: 48.31223969058969, longitude:  12.959643094792634},
                    {latitude: 50.31281785500094, longitude:  12.960823612887165},
                    {latitude: 47.31281654102718, longitude:  8.962966471196324},
                    {latitude: 47.30862993050194, longitude:  8.963243902017013},
                    {latitude: 47.30863115391583, longitude:  8.963151349827395},
                    {latitude: 47.30697209667029, longitude:  8.962058898768426},
                    {latitude: 47.30985701233802, longitude:  8.957498557565305}
                ]
        },
        {
               color: Qt.rgba(128, 80, 0, 0.5),
                path: [ //very big
                    {latitude: 45.30985701233802, longitude:  7.957498557565305},
                    {latitude: 41.31223969058969, longitude:  11.959643094792634},
                    {latitude: 54.31281785500094, longitude:  11.960823612887165},
                    {latitude: 45.31281654102718, longitude:  7.962966471196324},
                    {latitude: 45.30862993050194, longitude:  7.963243902017013},
                    {latitude: 45.30863115391583, longitude:  7.963151349827395},
                    {latitude: 45.30697209667029, longitude:  7.962058898768426},
                    {latitude: 45.30985701233802, longitude:  7.957498557565305}
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And then calling it like this:

```
Repeater {
        model: PolygonCoords.points
        MapPolygon {
            color:  Polygoncoords.points[index].color
            border {width: 2; color: "grey"}
            path:  PolygonCoords.points[index].path
        }
    }
```

Here I get no error, but the neither a MapPolygon on the map.

I also tried it with naming the `Item` with an id and calling it like this:

```
model: PolygonCoords.ItemID.points
```

But with this, I got the error: TypeError: Cannot read property points of undefined.

I further tried moving the repeater with the points together in another file and then just calling PolygonCoords. Again, no error and no MapPolygon:

```
Item {
 Repeater {
        model: PolygonCoords.points
        MapPolygon {
            color:  Polygoncoords.points[index].color
            border {width: 2; color: "grey"}
            path:  PolygonCoords.points[index].path
        }
    }

 property var points: [
        {
                color: Qt.rgba(0, 80, 128, 0.5),
                path: [ //very big
                    {latitude: 47.30985701233802, longitude:  8.957498557565305},
                    {latitude: 48.31223969058969, longitude:  12.959643094792634},
                    {latitude: 50.31281785500094, longitude:  12.960823612887165},
                    {latitude: 47.31281654102718, longitude:  8.962966471196324},
                    {latitude: 47.30862993050194, longitude:  8.963243902017013},
                    {latitude: 47.30863115391583, longitude:  8.963151349827395},
                    {latitude: 47.30697209667029, longitude:  8.962058898768426},
                    {latitude: 47.30985701233802, longitude:  8.957498557565305}
                ]
        },
        {
               color: Qt.rgba(128, 80, 0, 0.5),
                path: [ //very big
                    {latitude: 45.30985701233802, longitude:  7.957498557565305},
                    {latitude: 41.31223969058969, longitude:  11.959643094792634},
                    {latitude: 54.31281785500094, longitude:  11.960823612887165},
                    {latitude: 45.31281654102718, longitude:  7.962966471196324},
                    {latitude: 45.30862993050194, longitude:  7.963243902017013},
                    {latitude: 45.30863115391583, longitude:  7.963151349827395},
                    {latitude: 45.30697209667029, longitude:  7.962058898768426},
                    {latitude: 45.30985701233802, longitude:  7.957498557565305}
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And in the file with the map:

```
PolygonCoords {}
```

To make sure, I referenced PolygonCords right, I defined just a MapPolygon in it. This one was properly displayed on the map.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Is your model modifiable or static (it won't be modified)?

Comment: @GrecKo for now it is static, i plan to use the hardcoded MapPolygons for a presentation

Comment: ListElement can contain only simple values, like strings or numbers. See it [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html#details) for more info. From 5.11 it accept also function so you can try to wrap your value ie. you can return _path_ from a function.

Comment: @folibis Thank you for the clarification on that. I don't understand how I would return the path in a function. I still have to define the path for every Polygon? Do you have an example?

Comment: You could not use custom item in this way. You should either create singleton (and so you will be able to use it as `PolygonCoords.points`) or create item ie `PolygonCoords { id: poligonCoords }` and so use it as `poligonCoords.points`

Comment: @folibis Thank you so much! I got it working with the singleton !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example to illustrate idea I was talking about. I've used `Repeater` instead of `ListView` since it is more suitable for your purpose I guess. The data array could be stored in a different javascript file.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true
    property var points: [
        {
            color: Qt.rgba(0, 80, 128, 0.5),
            path: [
                {latitude:59.91288302222718, longitude:10.728799819940349},
                {latitude:59.91821810440818, longitude:10.737211227411649},
                {latitude:59.912323649434825, longitude:10.754119873037723},
                {latitude:59.90961270928307, longitude:10.764762878423767},
                {latitude:59.90165073245826, longitude:10.759441375730745},
                {latitude:59.908364741793115, longitude:10.748540878294307},
                {latitude:59.9010050830971, longitude:10.741846084608},
                {latitude:59.910387286199025, longitude:10.731632232668204},
            ]
        },
        {
            color: Qt.rgba(128, 80, 0, 0.5),
            path: [
                {latitude:59.92101437751683, longitude:10.77077102661346},
                {latitude:59.920842305970744, longitude:10.772916793815767},
                {latitude:59.9168413910999, longitude:10.772830963132293},
                {latitude:59.915206469874626, longitude:10.769741058354015},
                {latitude:59.91787393143297, longitude:10.765792846683212},
            ]
        }
    ]

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: Plugin { id: mapPlugin; name: "esri" }
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
        zoomLevel: 14
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                var coord = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y));
                console.log(coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
            }
        }
        Repeater {
            model: points
            MapPolygon {
                color: points[index].color
                border{ width: 1; color: "grey" }
                path: points[index].path
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works :) How can I move the points in a seperate file? I used Item as a wrapper. 
Then I tried it like this: model: filename.points 
color and path acordingly. I get no error, also no MapPolygon on my map. 
What I am missing? Does it only works with a javascript file? If possible I would like to have it in a QML-File.

Comment: You can store the dataset in a javascript file, QML file(singleton would be good I guess) or as a property as I did. The implementation depends on what you want to do. It hard to say why that doesn't work for you since I don't see a code.