# Pass C++ LineSeries to QML charts

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have to build a qml line serie chart. I must build the series to display in C++ because I've got many data to insert. I called my serie `QLineSeries * TaProbe` and I need to pass it to QML. How can I do it?
Below my QML code, where I want to load the TaProbe line serie

```
ChartView {
        id: chart
        anchors.fill: parent

            ValueAxis{
                id: xAxis
                min: 1.0
                max: 10.0
            },
            ValueAxis{
                id: yAxis
                min: 0.0
                max: 10.0
            }
}
```

Where I can load my C++ lineserie in the code above?

Can someone help me?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot pass `QLineSeries` to QML since `ChartView` has no possibility to add series. There is `ChartView.createSeries()` only. So the only way is to create a series in QML and pass array of points from C++ so you could add the points to the series using `XYSeries.append(x,y)`.

Answer (score -1):

So what you want is basically this:

```
ChartView {
    title: "Line"
    anchors.fill: parent
    antialiasing: true

    LineSeries {
        name: "LineSeries"
        XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
        XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 2.1 }
        XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 3.3 }
        XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 2.1 }
        XYPoint { x: 2.9; y: 4.9 }
        XYPoint { x: 3.4; y: 3.0 }
        XYPoint { x: 4.1; y: 3.3 }
    }
}
```

but the XYPoint are from your Cpp so you need to create this from your C++?

I did a similar thing with the Shape class of QML.

In the C++:

```
ShapeEditor::ShapeEditor() {
    _shapeInit = ""
            "import QtQuick 2.5;                                                 \n"
            "import QtQuick.Shapes 1.11;                                         \n"
            "Shape {                                                             \n"
            "    property string name: \"\"                                      \n"
            "    id: prlShape;                                                   \n"
            "    opacity: 0.8;                                                   \n"
            "    containsMode: Shape.FillContains;                               \n"
            "    function changeColor(newColor) {                                \n"
            "        shapePrlPath.fillColor = newColor;                          \n"
            "        shapePrlPath.strokeColor = newColor;                        \n"
            "    }                                                               \n"
            "    function changeOpacity(opac) {                                  \n"
            "        prlShape.opacity = opac;                                    \n"
            "    }                                                               \n"
            "    function destroyArea() {                                        \n"
            "        destroy();                                                  \n"
            "    }                                                               \n"
            "    ShapePath {                                                     \n"
            "         joinStyle: ShapePath.RoundJoin;                            \n"
            "         strokeColor: \"yellow\";                                   \n"
            "         fillColor: \"yellow\";                                     \n"
            "         id: shapePrlPath;                                          \n"
            "                                                                    ";
    _shapeEnd = " }}";
}

void ShapeEditor::createShapeItemFromPoint()
{
    QVector<QPoint> reorderedList = _pointList;
    _shapeForm = " startX:" + QVariant(reorderedList[0].x()).toString() + " ; startY: " + QVariant(reorderedList[0].y()).toString() + "    \n";
    for (int i = 1 ; i < reorderedList.size() ; i++) {
        _shapeForm += " PathLine { id: line" + QVariant(i).toString() + "; x: " + QVariant(reorderedList[i].x()).toString() + " ; y: " + QVariant(reorderedList[i].y()).toString() + "}    \n";
    }
    _shapeForm += " PathLine { id: line" + QVariant(reorderedList.size() + 1).toString() + "; x: " + QVariant(reorderedList[0].x()).toString() + " ; y: " + QVariant(reorderedList[0].y()).toString() + "}    \n";
    QObject* obj = _frontRoot->findChild<QObject*>("shapeEditor");
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "createShape", Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(_shapeInit + _shapeForm + _shapeEnd)))
}
```

qml:

```
Item {
  id: shapeEditor
  objectName: "shapeEditor"

  function createShape(str) {
    var item = Qt.createQmlObject(str, prlEditor, "shape");
  }
}
```

What you could do is to create your QML dynamic object dynamically. So create a QString in the C++ then send it to a javascript function via the invokeMethod.

You can follow this tutorial: [Dynamic QML Object Creation from JavaScript](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html).

Comment: Very nice ! I'm going to use it in my Prolog work - both SWI-Prolog and mine

Comment: a very strange way to create components. I don't think it is worth doing. You call a C++ function from QML to create code of component so it will be passed then to QML so then QML engine will pass it to C++ to create a component for QML -)

Comment: @folibis I also really don't like the way it has to be done. But the shape a Qml shape cannot just take a point2D array so if you have a better way feel free to share it with us.

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard, I've answered here an answer very closed to the issue a day ago. [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54439050/display-multiple-mappolygons-via-listview-and-listmodel), maybe it could be useful for you.

Comment: @folibis interresting, can it work dynamically? our points are created by the user at runtime.

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard, sure it can. The specific implementation depends on the goal but I see no obstacles to make it dynamically created. I guess one of the big advantages of QML is that you need to use C++ in a pinch, almost all you can do in pure QML/Javascript.

Comment: @folibis Ok I will try it when I will have some time, thanks